# Wordpress - using jQuery to toggle hidden text that's in a wp_query loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle

please help me with this:

I have four thumbnails across the top of my page and when they are clicked the content of the post toggles down. Problem is they stack on top of each other.

I need them to display one at a time. When one is clicked it toggles down, when another is clicked the "active" one slides away and the clicked one appears.

Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).slideToggle('hidden');
  }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="news-bar">
    <?php query_posts('cat=10'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <ul class="news-feed">
            <li>
                <a class="shadow" href="javascript:toggleDiv('post-<?php the_ID(); ?>');">
                    <?php
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        // the current post has a thumbnail
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                      echo '<div class="image-caption">' .get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt. '</div>';
                        } else {
                        // the current post lacks a thumbnail
                        }
                    ?>
                </a>
                </li>
        </ul>

            <div class="myContent" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">            
                    <h2><a href="<?php // the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php // the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p> 
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>  >
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use JQuery UI's built-in [accordion feature](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).  You should be able to see from the example on the linked page how to do it.  Basically, call `.accordion()` on your content wrapper and then it looks for sets of headings (which can be anything, in your case the `<a class="shadow">` thumbnails) and then expands/collapses the divs after them.

There is a simple code example on that page (you will need to reorganize your HTML markup some to get this to work) and you can see advanced options (defining what the 'headings' are, etc) on the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/).

JQuery UI is an add-on library that extends jQuery so you will need to include the script call in your header after the jQuery core script call.

**Edit**: rereading your post I realize you may not be wanting an accordion but rather tabs (so you have 4 thumbs next to each other at the top, with a content area below that is populated by whatever thumbnail is currently selected).  In that case you will want to look at the [jQuery UI Tabs widget](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) which is also very simple to implement ([documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you hide all of them before you reveal the one clicked.  Maybe try something like this:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $('#news-bar .myContent:not(#' + divId + ')').slideUp();
    $("#"+divId).slideToggle();
}
```

Not sure what the `hidden` is doing in the slideToggle, the only value it can be is a speed (and hidden is a speed).  If you wanted to add a class of `hidden`, you could do this:

```
$('#'+divId).slideToggle().toggleClass('hidden');
```

Also, you may want to add `style="display: none"` to the divs to hide them on page load.  Like so:

```
<div class="myContent" style="display: none" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```